# Referencing other notebooks in AWS EMR

Tags: pyspark, aws-serverless, aws-emr-studio

I am new to AWS EMR, and trying to configure to run it for a code which was developed on my local.

I am basically referencing notebooks within a Masternotebook, this set-up works on my local but not on AWS EMR.

I am trying to execute this line

`%run CreateSparkSession.ipynb`

and I get the below trace, I have tried converting it to .py file and have also tried giving the S3 path where the script is stored but it does not work.

Is there a way to make this work on AWS EMR and AWS EMR serverless?

[image]